# How to add data attributes to elements (<td> tags) when adding new row in datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I am adding new rows using JavaScript and inside a JavaScript function and I would like to add attributes and class names to the rows when they are created:

```
var rowNode = myTable.row.add([results.location_id, location_name.value, location_streetname.value , add_loc_hotline_phone ]).draw().node();

const $rowindex_ = $(rowNode).closest("tr");

const loc_city = $rowindex_.find('.location_address').attr('data-loc_city', location_city.value);
const loc_streetname = $rowindex_.find('.location_address').attr('data-loc_streetname', location_streetname.value);
```

Above you can see how I would update ALREADY existing attributes but HOW DO I CREATE THEM FIRST?

UPDATE:
I first need to create classNames for each of the rows because later I need to find  tags by class names. So how should I give them class names when the row is created?

Comment: Think you can do something like `$(rowNode).find('td:eq(0)').attr( 'myattr' ,'value');` You can see an example here https://jsfiddle.net/5cq8z0ky/

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen thanks but I have a dynamic table, so this `td:eq(0)`as I understand will just take the first cell right?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it still doesn't work. I need class names as well for each <td> tag

Comment: It would be better if you gave a sample table and sample attributes you have to assign. When you say "I need attributes in two first ones" or "I need class names for each td" you are not clear of what you need.

Comment: @ariel I think Carsten gave me the solution to creating attributes but now I am facing another issue, which is className. I found out that when a row is created it doesn't add class names as other <td> already have when the page is loaded. So how can I actually give them class names when the row is created?

Comment: If this question is answered, then you need to create another one with the new issue. But you can use `addClass`.

Comment: @ariel actually its not because I edited, its still the same question with some additional request. I know I can add by addClass but how to do that to a newly created <td> tags?

Answer (score 1):

To add hidden data information to a row, you can use the [`data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) function:

```
var rowNode = myTable.row
  .add([results.location_id, location_name.value, 
        location_streetname.value, add_loc_hotline_phone])
  .data({city: location_city.value, streetname: location_streetname.value})
  .draw().node();
```

To add a class you can use the [`createdCell`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell) callback:

```
$('#container').dataTable( {
  // ...
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": 0, // First column
    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
      td.classList.add(`column-id`);
    }
  } ]
} );
```